Why does it take so long for journals/committees to detect fabricated data or theses after submission?
I'm curious about the retraction process of papers or theses due to fabrication or dishonesty. Specifically, why is it that some papers or theses are retracted years after publication? Why can't supervisors or reviewers detect signs of dishonesty or malpractice from the beginning? Are there specific issues or procedures that prevent early detection of such problems?

what research have you done on this topic? I would encourage you to look around sites like https://retractionwatch.com/ and do some research before posting a question.

I've actually been reading Retraction Watch for a long time, which has given me some insights into the retraction process. Recently, I noticed that a few academic papers I had been following were retracted, which surprised me and prompted me to delve deeper into why these issues weren't caught earlier. This motivated me to ask this question, as I believe there's more to learn about the detection process.

I imagine it has to do with inherently trusting authors.

Detecting fabricated data seems to mostly rely on noticing data issues over a number of papers.

Please consider editing your answer to link to the source's you're read

Would you spend your time, your energy, and your research funding to repeat every single the experimental results published in the peer-reviewed journals?
If not, then you get the answer.

Why does fraudulent data pass peer review?
Experimental results (where something gets measured) cannot be duplicated without strenuous effort beyond the scope of peer review. Only recently does the scientific community value the worth of repeating experiments as something publishable.
Even in Computer Science, it is difficult to repeat experiments if they involve lots of computation.
Many write-ups are not detailed enough. Only rather recently can papers provide links to additional data such as raw measurements, questionnaires, etc. Things like code review are extremely involved so that faulty experimental setups are not easily detected.
Reviewing a mathematical argument is arduous work and errors can be undetected. Often, the reviewer falls into the same logical trap as the original writer.
However, many errors get caught in the review process and the wider public does not see them at all. There is a survivor bias in action when one is complaining about retractions.
Why does the scientific community not detect false results?
Well, on the one hand, it does happen. On the other hand, science is done by specialists, and many publications are meant for specialists, so that not too many people read publications at a deep level.
If one works in a field like medicine with many error sources, where the results have immediate impact, then one's work is subjected to more scrutiny.
Why is it possible to defraud
The scientific process like most social processes assumes a certain level of trust. A Ph.D. supervisor might guide a Ph.D. student in setting up an experiment, but ultimately trusts that the reported results are not falsified and that the experimental setup was done with sufficient care. It is easy for a wicked student to report false, but believable results, as the supervisor does not have the time to repeat the experiment independently.
In some cases of intentional academic fraud, the perpetrators had already acquired a reputation of brilliance that made it difficult for co-authors and other collaborators to challenge their results. Only once an initial chink in the armor arose, results were doubted and their behavior was questioned by their collaborators. Many retractions and then dismissal procedures resulted.
Many fields of study need to use statistics, which does not generate absolute truth. The classical use of statistics declares a null-hypothesis to be untenable because the experimental results can be reconciled with the null-hypothesis only by assuming very unlikely luck. This procedure has known error rates so that a certain number of results obtained in this way are false. Thus, if a group of researchers generates many hypotheses, then some spurious statistically significant results follow. This is p-value hunting. Publishing potentially spurious results still gives academic credits.
Conclusion
The scientific process as of today has problems. One is the sheer volume of publications that makes it difficult to find good peer review. Competitiveness among participants is another problem as it tempts people into careless but fast work. From there it is only a short step to falsify results (instead of waiting for them to be obtained), and another short step to just making up data. Duplicating experiments and carefully reading others' result is not rewarded.

A Ph.D. supervisor might guide a Ph.D. student in setting up an experiment, but ultimately trusts that the reported results are not falsified and that the experimental setup was done with sufficient care -- https://www.theguardian.com/education/2002/sep/18/science.highereducation

To quote from that article: "If my student came to me with earth-shattering data, you wouldn't be able to pry me out of the lab," says Rice University's Douglas Natelson. "I'd be in there turning the knobs myself." [UCLA's James] Heath echoes this sentiment: "I'd sit down there to see how this is being done. I'd demand to see it several times."

This is a somewhat (?) naive answer, but when a deception is initially successful, passing the review of experts, then it seems unlikely to be uncovered quickly thereafter. More likely it will take someone else keenly interested in the topic who has already got some evidence that the stated results of the original research don't hold up. That implies the development of alternate ideas and gathering evidence, which takes time.
In some fields (math) errors can be more obvious and can be caught more quickly, but, even there, if the flaw escapes initial review it can, quite easily, pass unnoticed for a while.
In some other fields, those with intense current interest, such flaws might be more likely to be caught early, but not every paper triggers hard analysis.
Moreover, in yet other fields, where statistical measures provide the evidence, errors occur, with well defined probability, and it might take someone willing to try to replicate the results to come to a more accurate conclusion. That takes time as well, and doesn't have a many clear rewards as doing some other research.

I feel like this question suggests its own answer. Fraud is difficult to detect because, for obvious reasons, the fraudsters are attempting to cover their tracks. Unless you assume the fraudsters are incompetent (I would guess instead that most of them are extremely clever - they're capable of writing research articles after all), then you should also conclude that they are more likely to be successful than unsuccessful. Ergo, reviewers can't just "detect signs of dishonesty or malpractice from the beginning" unless they are much smarter than the fraudsters - much smarter, since they'd need to detect the fraud using only general knowledge, without firsthand experience with the specific experiment.
You also ask about the supervisor. Why can't the supervisor, who presumably has easy firsthand access to the experiment, detect fraud? There's some level of survivorship bias here, since when the supervisor detects fraud you probably don't hear of it. Another issue is, sometimes (perhaps even most of the time) it's the supervisor that's committing the fraud. See e.g. the short list of academic retractions on Wikipedia.
